How to create a local PostGRE DB in DBVisualizer
I am trying to create a new local Postgre database with DBVisualizer (like MySQL) in my MAC.
But I am getting "Cannot connect to 'localhost' on port 5432".
I have tried all of the suggestions but nothing worked.
Can anyone help me with this?


Did you install and start a local PostgreSQL cluster on your laptop? And is it using port 5432? See https://postgresapp.com
